# How to modify magento admin login feature?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, captcha, admin-login

I have a requirement that , need to change complete design of magento login page and we need to add "captcha" in login form.

What are the modules and templates need to be overridden?

Answer (score 1):

For Captcha you can see https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/kbase/magento/magento-captcha.html

Admin theme 
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/v-admin.html
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/responsive-admin-template.html